variable service not initialized in the default constructor
When trying to launch my springboot services, I got this error :
java: variable service not initialized in the default constructor
Here is my controller code :
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/universites")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UniversiteController {
        
    private final UniversiteService service;
        
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void save(@RequestBody Universite universite){
        service.saveUniversite(universite);
    }
        
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Universite>> findAllUniversites() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.getAllUniversites());
    }
}

It is pointing at the  first line of my controller declaring the variable service is not initialized in the default constructor. I have also tried to resolve it by enabling annotation processing but it couldn't resolve my issue. How to figure it out ?

please add your service code.

Here is answer shown below
it's possible to forget the @Service annotation on your UniversiteService class.
